# utf-8 input characters in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, input-encodings

I would like to use special characters as the german umlaute ä, ö, ü, etc. (also ß) in the source file in plain TeX
as I may use them in LaTeX using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.
The use of 
\input utf8-pl
and typesetting with plain TeX leads to the error message "The encTeX extension of TeX is not found“.
Is there a way to circumvent this problem?
I am using TeXShop Version 3.75 on a MacBook Air with macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.1) and encTeX is apparently part of TeXShop.

Comment: Why not use `xetex` or `luatex`?

Comment: thanks for the link and great thanks to egreg for the file utfplainmac.tex; it solves perfectly my problem. Without using plain-t1.tex (and the ec-fonts chosen there), the appearance is exactly the same if I use é or \'e, and that is exactly what I wanted.